# Windows 10 laptop is loading the wrong desktop every time it reboots

Tags: windows-10, laptop, desktop, user

After rebooting a laptop, the entire desktop changed to a different one and many apps got uninstalled. From what I've been able to gather from my friend, it seems like they forced it off by holding the power button while it was in the middle of doing windows updates, and upon powering it back on this issue occured for the first time.

Looking at the desktop folder location properties I found that it was pointed to C:\Users\TEMP\Desktop instead of the owner's user profile. After changing the location path to their user, their desktop and all their files were restored. We reinstalled everything that went missing (Chrome, Microsoft office 365 suite, etc) and it was operational again.

That night, the laptop was powered off and upon booting up again it loaded back into the TEMP desktop. Is there a way to set it so that it loads their desktop upon rebooting?

Additional info - tried doing a system restore to before the change/wipe and it failed. Thank you.

Comment: It appears the profile default folders have been messed up. Try a tool such as Nirsoft's *Special Folders View*, https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/special_folders_view.html , to see where the Desktop folder points, and set it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Your Users Folders are messed up which is why System Restore did not fix it.  System Restore and Repair Install cannot and do not repair damaged User Profiles.

Back up your data (your system starts), and then do a fresh install of Windows 10.  This is the only practical and assured fix.